# How can the body reincarnate when the soul does not?

Tags: magic, death

I am known as Malevolencia the good, a warm hearted witch on the path to domination. Using my knowledge of magic, I have discovered a way to extend my life using the souls of others. This ritual takes place over the course of many years and requires multiple steps to ensure completion.

There are 5 parts that make up a soul, which are condensed into a stable form and  held together by various spiritual components:

1. Raw mana- the life energy of the soul.
2. Ka- seat of a person's Emotions (love, fear, anger, etc)
3. Ba- seat of a person's memories
4. Sed- a person's spiritual I.D. (how the universe identifies and keeps track of them.
5. Un- the connector that binds their soul to their physical body and the physical realm.

By separating the soul into its parts and breaking them down into their originial elements, I can reconstruct my own soul from the remains of theirs. First, I must find a candidate who's mana signature is similar to my own, similar to an organ transplant. The best matches would be those of my family, the closest of which are my children as they have descended from me. Whenever I have a son/daughter, the process would begin, where I would raise them as my apprentice and can keep close watch over them.

After I die, my soul will transfer into the new body, which is kept in a magically induced coma and stored away for future use. After an incubation period, the host's soul is consumed in the process, and I emerge as a younger version of my original form. By reincarnation myself through my own children, I have been able to extend my life for many centuries.

Although some may call me a monster, I actually have a good reason for this: I am on a quest for immortality so I can conquer the world and subject it to my every whim, thereby providing the justification that makes my motives sympatheic. However, after the 7th body, I noticed a problem. Although my physical form comes back fresh, my soul is getting weaker. This is similar to a photocopier, where each successive copy fades more than the previous one. This makes it harder to perform the transfer, and more difficult to access my own mana.

By this logic however, my physical form should be coming back old and decrepit, with various flaws. This is not the case, for even though my soul is weaker, my body is perfectly rejuvenated as it was when the ritual began. How can this be the case?

Comment: All hail the ancient god [Cronus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronus)!

Comment: A few questions: you use both 'rejuvenate' and 'reincarnate' in your question. The words have distinctly different meanings - 'rejuvenate' would be returning youth to your body, while 'reincarnate' suggests the old body is destroyed or abandoned and a new one manufactured in some way. Which is it?

Comment: How does the new body creation work? Is it manufactured from thin air, or some other process?

Comment: @James McLean added more to question.

Comment: Look up the definition of the term 'incarnation'. Another synonym for 'incarnation' is 'embody'. How can a body again embody another body? Only the soul can embody or take upon a new body. Body can embody an item of clothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's not the time, but the environment itself.** (I am new to this soul/magical issues, So I beg you pardon in advance)

Let's say, There two types of the environment on earth, one is the physical and another is mana based.

While the physical environment does not change over a long period of centuries, the mana environment is extremely sensitive to the collective consciousness of the beings living in it, and each soul that is living within this environment needs to be in sync with it to remain perfectly healthy.

While your original soul is fit for today's environment and you are using the framework and specs of your original soul, after 7 generations (over 200 years later), it gets out of sync with the mana environment.

This mana environment is in-itself a conscious being and can detect a soul that is out of place and thus release antibodies to retrieve such souls, thus making it weaker, this removal process itself may take another 200 years, but it is a degrading process.

Now, we have two questions, How to fix this and Why does the soul gets out of sync.

**How to fix this** is simple, just have a right mix of mana genetics in your revived soul, that is, instead of totally degrading the soul of your son, preserve some of its mana within you, it will help you remain in sync, thus making your revived soul healthier. (Just like the theory of evolution)

**Why does the soul gets out of sync**, well these are one of the greatest mysteries of the magical realm, but as per one of the theories, It is mechanism of earth's mana environment to reclaim all its souls back into it at one point or another, all souls are born from it and all souls must get submerged into it at someday, so this conscious mana being keeps on making subtle changes to the environment to detect the old and out of sync souls (like an antivirus software keeps on releasing updates) so that these souls can be retrieved for purification purposes.

Comment: The ‘Soul’ app requires an update or it may stop working. Please visit the occult store to update.

Answer (score 3):

**Best Match isn't a Perfect Match**

Just like organ donations, a match isn't perfect. Recipients need to take anti rejection drugs to stop the body from attacking the part.

While children might be a match, they aren't as good as an identical twin or a clone but if you don't have a spare clone, they're better than dying.

What you end up with is a soul where parts have been taken from another soul and they're not perfect. Each subsequent regeneration means more and more bits don't quite match leaving the caster weaker and weaker.

A less compatible match means you are even weaker thus the need for the children.

A sweet twist could be the mother cheats on the evil villain and the child isn't his leaving him in big trouble trying to steal this soul.

Comment: I always assumed "Malevolencia" was a female witch! Aside from surrogacy, I have actually heard of a IRL case where the mother wasn't the biological mother when DNA of the child she birthed was tested (vanishing twin syndrome was the cause). However pretty sure most mothers know the child they are carrying is theirs.

Comment: The child could be swapped out at birth. Happens accidentally all the time. Could be a deliberate action to take out an enemy.

Answer (score 1):

Body and soul are seperate things with different life expectancy but still the same in many ways, like a skin cell and a brain cell.

Every time you rejuvinate your body is regrown as the 25 year old body, which will then age normally until death. The soul or container of that soul also ages but much more slowly. But during the rejuvination process it isnt actually replaced, but transferred each time. Like a cell dividing itself and eventually showing signs of wear that is our aging process, the rejuvination keeps wearing the soul down. And just like a cell that ages much faster if it has to divide much faster in a short time to heal wounds your soul will have much more wear during the rejuvination process.

We from NotEvil corp advize to stimulate twin or triplet births, and to sap the energy of all children simultaneously. This larger influx of energy allows alternative treatments to rejuvinate your old body or possibly shore up the soul.